# R: Positioning labels and axes with rgl.plot3d

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a 3d scatter plot using rgl.plot3d. However, the default positioning of the labels and axes is not satisfactory. E.g., the y-axis label is positioned on the far side, while I want it to be positioned on the near side. The x-axis ticks are positioned at the far top. I went them to be positioned at the near bottom. I looked at `?par3d`but couldn't find anything that would help me. Is it possible to do this in rgl? Code and data are given below. Thank you.

## Code

```
d <- read.table(file='myfile.dat', header=F)
plot3d(
    d,
    xlim=c(0,20),
    ylim=c(0,20),
    zlim=c(0,10000),
    box=F,
    type='p',
    size=5,
    col=d[,1]
)
mtext3d(text='Test', edge='y+-', line=2)
axes3d(
    edges=c('x--', 'y+-', 'z--'),
    labels=T
)
lines3d(
    d,
    lwd=2,
    col=d[,1]
)
grid3d(side=c('x', 'y+', 'z'))
```

## Data

```
11    2    2
NA    NA    NA
10    2    2
NA    NA    NA
13    2    1
NA    NA    NA
15    2    1
NA    NA    NA
5    2    11
5    3    10
5    4    16
5    5    34
5    6    102
5    7    294
5    8    682
5    9    1439
5    10    2646
5    11    3615
5    12    2844
5    13    1394
NA    NA    NA
4    2    10
4    3    4
4    4    4
4    5    10
4    6    38
4    7    132
4    8    396
4    9    976
4    10    2121
4    11    4085
4    12    6261
4    13    6459
4    14    4238
4    15    1394
NA    NA    NA
7    2    3
NA    NA    NA
6    2    2
NA    NA    NA
9    2    8
9    3    6
9    4    4
9    5    5
NA    NA    NA
8    2    4
8    3    10
8    4    22
8    5    52
8    6    126
8    7    264
8    8    478
8    9    729
8    10    943
8    11    754
8    12    382
NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: When I suggested you post another question I included the request that you include data (and I assumed you would post the code as well.) You do know that you can "grab" the plotting frame and do an interactive 3d rotatation of the plot frame, right? That will change the positioning of the default axis labels.

Comment: You did look at `?axes3d` (and especially the "Details" section), right?

Comment: @DWin That was another problem I was having. This was unrelated to that and didn't require code and/or data, so I didn't post it. I have a few more problems view view3d etc that I'll be posting about in a bit too. In any case, I am getting rather tired of R. The rgl package especially seems very buggy. I'm thinking of going back to Gnuplot.

Comment: @DWin also, yes,  I know you can manually rotate the frame. But nothing I do gets me the results I want.

Comment: But does @DWin's answer satisfy you? If not, please specify why not -- and ideally provide a reproducible example. I agree that in this case code is not *necessary* to see what you want, but having a framework to start from makes answering questions quicker and easier ...

Comment: @BenBolker I was just testing out DWin's recommendations. Please see my comment below as to how far I've gotten. And I shall add the code in a bit if you think it'll help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at `?axis3d` where the use of the 'edges' parameter is described. If you want the x-axis tick labels at the front-bottom and the y-axis on the near+bottom side,  you would first build the plot using `..., axes=FALSE,` and with the focus unchanged issue this command at the console:

```
axes3d( edges=c("x--", "y--", "z") )
```

I have not yet figured out whether it is possible to remove an existing axis in an rgl plot.

Comment: "Maybe" is the right word. If so, you  need discover the ids and then use `rgl.pop( type = "bboxdeco", id = ..number.. ) `

Comment: @DWin ok thanks.  That worked for me. I also figured out that I can place the labels at my desired positions with mtext3d. However, plot3d creates some default labels. How do I remove those?

Comment: @DWin also, I would like to rotate the labels. Is that possible?

Comment: @DWin I appreciate your help. I spent the better part of the last two days googling and reading the help myself. I only came to this forum when I was absolutely frustrated with my lack of success. And default labels aren't being suppressed by axes=F. It sets the labels to V1, V2 and V3. I googled that before asking you as well. No answer anywhere. I googled the rotation question as well first. There was one other person who asked the same question on another forum, but he got no answer. Please rest assured, that asking this forum is a last desperate attempt for me.

Comment: @DWin never mind about the axis labels. Setting them to empty strings solves that problem.

Comment: It would help if you made the distinction between tick labels and axis labels. Especially so since you had set my mental context by asking about tick labels.) The axis labels should get suppressed with `xlab="", ylab="", zlab=""`.

Comment: @DWin sorry for the confusion. I do make that distinction in my original question. Anyway, thanks. I figured that out just before your reply :)